# R gt summary_rows Ratio Total Row

Tags: r, gt

I am using the great [`gt`](https://blog.rstudio.com/2020/04/08/great-looking-tables-gt-0-2/) package to help make nice looking tables in `R`. I really like how I can use it to make Total columns, but I am struggling in trying to do anything beyond a simple `sum` or `mean`. I need do something more like a SUMPRODUCT for a couple of my columns. Let's say that I have the following data. It has a `denom` column which I want to divide a couple of numerators by.

```
library(dplyr)
library(gt)
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(some_letter = sample(letters, size = 10, replace = FALSE),
                 denom = sample(1:100, size = 10, replace = FALSE), 
                 num1 = sample(100:200, size = 10, replace = FALSE),
                 num2 = sample(100:200, size = 10, replace = FALSE)) %>% 
  mutate(rat1 = round(num1 / denom, 2), 
         rat2 = round(num2 / denom, 2))

some_letter denom num1 num2  rat1  rat2
1            y    54  188  119  3.48  2.20
2            d    74  143  127  1.93  1.72
3            g     7  178  200 25.43 28.57
4            a    73  132  143  1.81  1.96
5            b    79  183  186  2.32  2.35
6            k    85  134  169  1.58  1.99
7            n    37  169  139  4.57  3.76
8            r    89  173  197  1.94  2.21
9            w    94  141  124  1.50  1.32
10           j    34  137  195  4.03  5.74
```

So I would like to get a `TOTAL` column that is the `sum` for `denom`, `num1` and `num2`. This is super easy with `gt` using the `summary_rows` function. But the `TOTAL` I need for the two ratio columns is not just that `sum`. I can't just add up `rat1` and `rat2` to get the correct ratio. The `TOTAL` column for those needs to be the `sum(num1) / sum(denom)` and `sum(num1) / sum(denom)`.

So this works for the easy columns.

```
gt(df) %>% 
  summary_rows(fns = list(TOTAL = "sum"), 
               columns = vars(denom, num1, num2))
```

[image]

For those other columns, I have tried the following to no avail.

```
gt(df) %>% 
  summary_rows(fns = list(TOTAL = "sum"), 
               columns = vars(denom, num1, num2)) %>% 
  summary_rows(fns = list(TOTAL = ~sum(.) / sum(denom)), columns = vars(rat1, rat2))

gt(df) %>% 
  summary_rows(fns = list(TOTAL = "sum"), 
               columns = vars(denom, num1, num2)) %>% 
  summary_rows(fns = list(TOTAL = sum(.) / sum(denom)), columns = vars(rat1, rat2))
```

And I know that I can compute this separately and `rbind` it onto the bottom, but the `summary_rows` function provides really fantastic formatting without doing anything extra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm having the same problem, and have found no better solution, other than to tidy up the way the code passes `r1_total` and `r2_total` to the `summary_rows( )` function:

```
r1_total <- sum(df$num1) /  sum(df$denom)
r2_total <- sum(df$num2) /  sum(df$denom)

gt(df) %>% 
  summary_rows(fns = list(TOTAL = "sum"), columns = vars(denom, num1, num2)) %>% 
  summary_rows(fns = list(TOTAL = ~ c(r1_total), columns = vars(rat1)) %>% 
  summary_rows(fns = list(TOTAL = ~ c(r2_total), columns = vars(rat2))
```

OR

```
gt(df) %>% 
  summary_rows(fns = list(TOTAL = "sum"), columns = vars(denom, num1, num2)) %>% 
  summary_rows(fns = list(TOTAL = ~ sum(df$num1) /  sum(df$denom) ), columns = vars(rat1)) %>% 
  summary_rows(fns = list(TOTAL = ~ sum(df$num2) /  sum(df$denom) ), columns = vars(rat2))
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution is so bad that it should say five Hail Marys and 2 Our Fathers, but it works...

You can compute the ratios separately and then throw them into you "`fns`" call. Looks like it can't just take a double, so you have to divide by the `sum(1)`. Ugly for sure and probably could be cleaned up a little with a function, but it seems to work.

```
r1_total <- sum(df$num1) /  sum(df$denom)
r2_total <- sum(df$num2) /  sum(df$denom)

gt(df) %>% 
  summary_rows(fns = list(TOTAL = "sum"), 
               columns = vars(denom, num1, num2)) %>% 
  summary_rows(fns = list(TOTAL = ~ r1_total / sum(1) ), columns = vars(rat1)) %>% 
  summary_rows(fns = list(TOTAL = ~ r2_total / sum(1) ), columns = vars(rat2))
```

[image]